# Are there any dark themes (like Zenburn) for Coldfusion Builder?

Tags: coldfusion, themes, coldfusionbuilder

I am looking for dark themes for Coldfusion Builder but google does not find anything?

Do you have one or know a place where i can get some?

Comment: I would like to know if there are any dark theme for CF Builder 3. None of my COL files for dark themes are being accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Russ Johnson ( http://twitter.com/russ_johnson ) is working on one.  [Download from GitHub](http://github.com/russjohnson/Cloudy-Theme)

Comment: ok forgot to say that i use cfbuilder as an eclipse plugin. In eclipse i am not able to import anything for html,css,js or xml

Comment: found the options for html, css and js. you have to look in the html editor in the eclipse preferences.

Answer (score 2):

I did not find luck with any of the above suggestions while using CF Builder 3.0

WHAT WORKED:So I went to http://guari.github.io/eclipse-ui-theme/

Followed the 'Update Site' method of installation.

Restart Eclipse and go to Window > Preferences > General > Appearance;

Select MoonRise (standalone)

Voila.. its done.

Comment: Wouldn't say "Voila" as most of the code is unreadable until you go play with the colors, but at least this works for CFB3

Comment: I agree the enthusiasm is bit high. But after a strenuous search getting a editable theme for CF builder was exhilarating :-)

Answer (score 0):

I really like the "Green Chaud" one that was on the [Aptana Forums here](http://forums.aptana.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=1847) and and tweaked it for CF but it is now not accessible :( Hopefully the link will come back. If not I will post mine.

Here is a PHP variation on it that is pretty close on a [blog](http://www.nightlion.net/themes/2009/aptana-dark-color-theme/) making them work with CFB is pretty easy.