# Are there any ColdFusion Builder 2016 Themes or anyway to create any?

Tags: coldfusion, themes, coldfusionbuilder

Are there any ColdFusion Builder 2016 Themes or anyway to create any?

I prefer a black background and colored text.

Comment: If it's still built on top of the Eclipse IDE, just look for Eclipse themes.

Comment: This is old, but may provide a starting point  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1847362/are-there-any-dark-themes-like-zenburn-for-coldfusion-builder